# IR blaster of Xiaomi Redmi 3s prime is not working properly. What to do?

Tags: remote-control, xiaomi

I am trying to use the IR blaster to control my set top box and TV. While the remote for TV is working fine. But the remote for Dish TV set top box is not responding. How to solve this issue? Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Did you configure the IR precisely to the model of your TV set-top box? Could you provide your TV box details? (brand, model)

Comment: I open the remote app and download the Dish TV set top box remote directly. My TV is of LG company and TV remote is working fine but set top box remote is not working. It's brand is Dish TV